# NSUserDefaults returns null for valueForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

In my app, I am trying to access a value in NSUserDefaults which is stored by libXYZ.a file. But I am getting a null value.
While saving in lib file I am using `setValue: forKey:`, While accessing in app i am using `valueForKey:`

Can we access userdefaults outside of lib file ?

Comment: You should check if you are setting nil to the `NSUserDefaults `, also check if key are correct or not

Comment: @Tj3n:  I am not setting nil, and key is same. Can we access userdefaults outside of a lib file

Comment: Have you write `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` just after updating the `userDefaults`?

Comment: @TheTiger : yes

Comment: Can you please show the code? Both where you are setting and where getting

Answer (score 0):

You should use `objectForKey` instead of `valueForKey`. It must be using `setObject: forKey:` in the file for setting the value. `valueForKey` is based on **KVO** whereas `objectForKey` is based on **dictionary**.

Comment: While saving I am using setValue: forKey:

Comment: Whenever you are working with keys and values, always use setObject:forKey: and when you need to work with KVP, use setValue:forKey:

Comment: So, use setObject: forKey

Comment: So it failed even after using both setObject:forKey for setting and objectForKey for getting ?

Comment: Yes it failed. Still I am getting null